# Use AntMedia server with standard WebRTC APIs

Tags: java, codenameone, ant-media-server-sdk

My problem is that I need to use AntMedia Enteprise with these Java APIs, which are compliant with the WebRTC standard:
https://shannah.github.io/CN1WebRTC/javadoc/

but AntMedia's documentation only refers to their own SDKs, without indicating how to use their server with third-party software (more precisely, instructions for third-party software are there in the case of RMTP, but not WebRTC):
https://github.com/ant-media/Ant-Media-Server/wiki

I'm addressing my question to those who are already familiar with AntMedia or who develop it. Thanks.